# How to input a sentence in Java

Tags: java

The code I have written takes as input just a single string and not a whole sentence and I want a whole sentence to be taken as input:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i; 
        i= scan.nextInt();
        double d;
        d=scan.nextDouble();
        String s;
        s=scan.next();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

The test case is "Welcome to Java" and it's just showing "Welcome" in the output. Everything else is working fine. Please help.

Comment: use `scan.nextLine()` instead of `scan.next()`

Comment: Its not showing anything now...Plz help

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/4121347) for that.

Comment: Your question does not contain the test cases. Make sure to always create a [mcve], emphasis on complete. Otherwise we can't help that much and, as you have seen, a discussion starts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use `scan.nextLine();` to read the entire line.

Comment: Its showing this now :-Nice try, but you did not pass this test case.
Input (stdin)
42
3.1415
Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!
Your Output (stdout)
String: 
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42
Expected Output
String: Welcome to HackerRank's Java tutorials!
Double: 3.1415
Int: 42

Comment: int i; 
i= scan.nextInt();
double d;
d=scan.nextDouble();

Comment: its showing nothing now....the word 'Welcome' was being displayed earlier but after making the changes it shows nothing--just a blank space

Comment: d=scan.nextDouble();                                                                                   scan.next();                                                                                                    s=scan.nextLine(); this will work

Comment: when reading double,int types third time when reading string the  scan object skips so,scan.next() represents skip so,the next scan.nextLine() works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115585/discussion-between-sarthak-rana-and-guru-001).

Answer (score 10):

you can try the following, it will work.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {    
        // Create a new scanner object
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

        // Scan the integer which is in the first line of the input
        int i = scan.nextInt(); 

        // Scan the double which is on the second line
        double d = scan.nextDouble(); 

        /* 
         * At this point, the scanner is still on the second line at the end
         * of the double, so we need to move the scanner to the next line
         * scans to the end of the previous line which contains the double. 
         */
        scan.nextLine();    

        // reads the complete next line which contains the string sentence            
        String s = scan.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
  }
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Please add Few line comment, it would increase readability of of answer and it's good practice
your answer is well formatted and have meaning its better to read this help gape for better answer writing practice

Answer (score 2):

You should put a `scan.nextLine()` after the above integer scan and the double scan. Then use `String s = scan.nextLine()`. Like this,

```
int i = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
double d = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, this is working code, I tried with IntelliJ and Online compilers Like Hacker Rank.

```
    public class Solution {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i = scan.nextInt();
            double d = scan.nextDouble();
            scan.nextLine();
            String s = scan.nextLine();   

            System.out.println("String: " + s);
            System.out.println("Double: " + d);
            System.out.println("Int: " + i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using `next()` . This is use for input one **word**.

You can use `nextLine()` to input **sentence** in java.

example :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        s=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
    }
}
```

But above code(question) you are taking three inputs. You use `nextLine()` after `nextDouble()`.
In this case `nextLine()` read input as a newline character of the **double input**.
So output String is empty. To avoid that use another `nextLine()` after the `nextDouble()`. This `nextLine()` read the newline character of the double input and next `nextLine()` read the **sentence**.

So try this out :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        String s = scan.nextLine();


        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Thank You...!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Solution {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       //For input a Integer
       int i = scan.nextInt(); 

       //For input a Double
       double d = scan.nextDouble(); 

       //For input a String
       scan.nextLine(); //For using to get the input string that was skipped of the Scanner object.(Use it when scan a string after scanning different type of  variables.)
       String s = scan.nextLine();

       //For print String, Double and Integer variable
    
       System.out.println("String: " + s);
       System.out.println("Double: " + d);
       System.out.println("Int: " + i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();

        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        Double b = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        String a = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String: "+a);
        System.out.println("Double: "+b);
        System.out.println("Int: "+c);
    }
```